# ruby aws s3: batch_delete! is not removing all files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Problem with removing files from aws s3: sometimes *batch_delete!* method lefts some files after removing. A mainfolder contains multiple folders, each folder contains multiple files.
Used gem: gem 'aws-sdk-s3'

```
  prefix = ['prod', 'mainfolder', 7.days.ago].join('/')
  objects = s3.bucket(AWSS3.config[:s3][:bucket]).objects(prefix: prefix)
  msg = "removing #{objects.count} files from #{prefix} folder."
  objects.batch_delete!
  $mongodb['results'].insert_one(msg: (msg + "Done. Now the folder contains: #{objects.count} files."))
```

For the last 8 runs I met with 2 bad removings (1 and 8 files left in the inner folders.)

Removing count: ~310_000 files